# python - Creating array of combinations with arrays instead of itertools combinations

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, optimization

I wrote a python script that needs a function to generate a random combination of numbers that average to an inputted average based on a minimum and maximum values to be used and the number of numbers that should be used to generate the combination.

I am bottlenecked with this function because this must loop for each month in the analysis and then again for a few thousand simulations.

I need to be able to run with a larger number of simulations and looking for a way that this can be modified to utilize arrays and built in numpy arithmetic instead of for loops.

This is how I have the function written currently:

```py
def deal_months(ccc, num_deals, min, max):
    if len(ccc) != len(num_deals):
        raise Exception("ccc is not the same length as num_deals")
    integers = list(range(min, max + 1))
    combinations = [list(combinations_with_replacement(integers, 1)),
                    list(combinations_with_replacement(integers, 2)),
                    list(combinations_with_replacement(integers, 3)),
                    list(combinations_with_replacement(integers, 4))]
    final_combos = []
    for ccc, num_deals in zip(ccc, num_deals):
        if num_deals == 0: 
            final_combos += [0]
            continue
        matching_combos = [combo for combo in combinations[num_deals - 1] if sum(combo) / num_deals == ccc]
        if not matching_combos: 
            final_combos += [0]
            continue
        rand = random.randint(0, len(matching_combos) - 1)
        final_combos += [matching_combos[rand]]
    return final_combos
```

This is being used to forecast revenue in a business model and `ccc` and `num_deals` should be a list or array of values with a length equal to the total months in the analysis.

In the model `ccc` is a random normal distribution with mean 8 and std 3, rounded , `num_deals` is between 0-4, min is 0 and max is 36.

Comment: What are the typical sizes of the numbers you are dealing with? I.e. `len(ccc)` and `min`, `max`?

Comment: Can you also please provide some actual sample values to be used for benchmarking? [mre]

Comment: Are `min` and `max` fixed parameters or would the function be called with many different possible values... ?

Comment: Do you absolutely need a uniform sampling from the matching combos or a bias would be acceptable?

Comment: if you were to use `product` rather than `combinations_with_replacement` would it be ok?

Comment: Updated the question for sample values, min and max are fixed. I am not sold on using combinations_with_replacement and looking for a more time efficient solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using any numpy fancy vectorized computation, you can already greatly reduce the time (assuming you are repeating this for a large number of samples N) by only doing each computation once by precomputing and memorizing everything:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
import random
import timeit


N = 10000

ccc = [round(random.normalvariate(8,3)) for _ in range(N)]
num_deals = [random.randint(0,4) for _ in range(N)]


# first benchmark your solution:
def deal_months(ccc, num_deals, min=0, max=36):
    if len(ccc) != len(num_deals):
        raise Exception("ccc is not the same length as num_deals")
    integers = list(range(min, max + 1))
    combinations = [list(combinations_with_replacement(integers, 1)),
                    list(combinations_with_replacement(integers, 2)),
                    list(combinations_with_replacement(integers, 3)),
                    list(combinations_with_replacement(integers, 4))]
    final_combos = []
    for ccc, num_deals in zip(ccc, num_deals):
        if num_deals == 0: 
            final_combos += [0]
            continue
        matching_combos = [combo for combo in combinations[num_deals - 1] if sum(combo) == ccc * num_deals]
        if not matching_combos: 
            final_combos += [0]
            continue
        rand = random.randint(0, len(matching_combos) - 1)
        final_combos += [matching_combos[rand]]
    return final_combos

%timeit deal_months(ccc, num_deals)
# 10.2 s ± 71.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)



from collections import defaultdict

# now compare with mine:
def deal_months_2(ccc, num_deals, min=0, max=36):
    if len(ccc) != len(num_deals):
        raise Exception("ccc is not the same length as num_deals")
    integers = list(range(min, max + 1))
    all_matching_combos = defaultdict(list)
    for n in range(1,5):
        for c in combinations_with_replacement(integers, n):
            mean, rest = divmod(sum(c), n)
            if rest:
                continue
            all_matching_combos[(mean, n)].append(c)
    final_combos = []
    for c, n in zip(ccc, num_deals):
        matching_combos = all_matching_combos[(c, n)]
        if not matching_combos: 
            final_combos.append(0)
            continue
        final_combos.append(random.choice(matching_combos))
    return final_combos
    
%timeit deal_months_2(ccc, num_deals)
# 14.4 ms ± 576 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Note that most of that time is the precomputation, once this is done sampling even a large amount of times becomes trivial:

```
def get_all_matching_combos(min=0, max=36):
    integers = list(range(min, max + 1))
    all_matching_combos = defaultdict(list)
    for n in range(1,5):
        for c in combinations_with_replacement(integers, n):
            mean, rest = divmod(sum(c), n)
            if rest:
                continue
            all_matching_combos[(mean, n)].append(c)
    return all_matching_combos

%timeit get_all_matching_combos()
# 11.9 ms ± 12.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)


def sample(ccc, num_deals, all_matching_combos=get_all_matching_combos()):
    if len(ccc) != len(num_deals):
        raise Exception("ccc is not the same length as num_deals")
    final_combos = []
    for c, n in zip(ccc, num_deals):
        matching_combos = all_matching_combos[(c, n)]
        if not matching_combos: 
            final_combos.append(0)
            continue
        final_combos.append(random.choice(matching_combos))
    return final_combos


N = 10000
ccc = [round(random.normalvariate(8,3)) for _ in range(N)]
num_deals = [random.randint(0,4) for _ in range(N)]
%timeit sample(ccc, num_deals)
# 2.53 ms ± 7.63 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

You can also convince yourself that my magic is equivalent to your original code by setting the random seed to ensure same results:

```
def deal_months(ccc, num_deals, min=0, max=36):
    if len(ccc) != len(num_deals):
        raise Exception("ccc is not the same length as num_deals")
    integers = list(range(min, max + 1))
    combinations = [list(combinations_with_replacement(integers, 1)),
                    list(combinations_with_replacement(integers, 2)),
                    list(combinations_with_replacement(integers, 3)),
                    list(combinations_with_replacement(integers, 4))]
    final_combos = []
    random.seed(0) # <<< ensure same sampling
    for ccc, num_deals in zip(ccc, num_deals):
        if num_deals == 0: 
            final_combos += [0]
            continue
        matching_combos = [combo for combo in combinations[num_deals - 1] if sum(combo) == ccc * num_deals]
        if not matching_combos: 
            final_combos += [0]
            continue
        rand = random.randint(0, len(matching_combos) - 1)
        final_combos += [matching_combos[rand]]
    return final_combos


def deal_months_2(ccc, num_deals, min=0, max=36):
    if len(ccc) != len(num_deals):
        raise Exception("ccc is not the same length as num_deals")
    integers = list(range(min, max + 1))
    all_matching_combos = defaultdict(list)
    for n in range(1,5):
        for c in combinations_with_replacement(integers, n):
            mean, rest = divmod(sum(c), n)
            if rest:
                continue
            all_matching_combos[(mean, n)].append(c)
    final_combos = []
    random.seed(0) # <<< ensure same sampling
    for c, n in zip(ccc, num_deals):
        matching_combos = all_matching_combos[(c, n)]
        if not matching_combos: 
            final_combos.append(0)
            continue
        final_combos.append(random.choice(matching_combos))
    return final_combos

N = 1000
ccc = [round(random.normalvariate(8,3)) for _ in range(N)]
num_deals = [random.randint(0,4) for _ in range(N)]
d = deal_months(ccc, num_deals)
d2 = deal_months_2(ccc, num_deals)
assert d == d2
```